# Is it possible to change the firmware of a mouse?

Tags: mouse, malware, firmware

Recently, I plugged in my Trust GXT 130 to a school computer and am now worried about hardware malware. I read that it is necessary to know the address of the memory that has to be accessed and that manufacturers usially provide tools to change the firmware. When i went on Trust's website, I only saw the possibility to download documents about the mouse. I couldn't find such tools on Trust's website but that doesn't mean such tools don't exist. How easy is it to and is it even possible to replace the normal firmware with some malware?

Comment: It really is very unlikely that the firmware of your mouse is changed. First of all, it needs a very directed attack towards your specific mouse. Given how many mouses there are, it just is not practical, and there are way better ways to target you specifically if that is the requirement. Then your mouse can't even firmware upgrade. A mouse with firmware upgrade is a novelty or a manufacturer thing. Few mice (compared to all existing mice) have consumer firmware upgradability.

Comment: That said, this seems like an X-Y problem. You experienced something, did some research of your own, came to a conclusion that is possibly the wrong one, and now look for a solution based on that conclusion. If you tell us your original problem, we can assist you far better.

Comment: Basically - if anyone wants to target you enough to hack your mouse... you pretty much are out of luck. [Mickens](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/08/mickens_on_secu.html) comes to mind

Comment: The original problem was me simply being worried about my mouse having a virus after being connected to a school computer, wondering if it was safe to use it. Nothing in particular happened.

Comment: This, then is the equivalent of worrying about becoming pregnant from sitting on toilet seats. ie, unfounded, irrational fear.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at some assumptions needed for this to happen;

- Assuming there is an attacker out to do so, the attacker would have to know the exact model of mouse and reverse engineer the (non-public) firmware for it. Given the millions of mice available, and generally how basic USB mice dont allow you to reflash over USB (unless, again, you have the manufacturer tool (with capability to read firmware or electronics tools to do so) or its a mouse with custom macros - in which case only a small piece of ROM is available to exploit), they would have to make a one-size-fits-all USB firmware virus. And that is NOT easy, if at all possible
- All of the school computers needs to have the program running in the background to detect the mouse, and inject the malcious modified firmware (which, by the way, has to fit on the tiny processor ROM that operates the mouse). They would almost undoubtedly need administrator rights for it to run in the background before any user has logged on, or the school admin would have to be a skilled firmware expert and has to have gone rogue.
- The malicious firmware itself would have to be engineered to work on any platform (for it to be feasible as a virus), and inject itself silently via USB. Yes, this is slightly more possible because of things like BadUSB, Rubber Ducky USB, even an Arduino Pro Micro can inject keystrokes, but to type any command it has to get into a command utility first (terminal/command prompt). And if you have re-designed the key combos to open them, or even if you are holding down a modifier key, it wont work and wont be able to inject any keystrokes at all. (Another way would be for it to fool the computers processor into accepting instructions straight from the serial device, but this is extremely unlikely, to the point where the computer itself would have to be made vulnerable for it. Passing the USB to the OS seems the safest way and its what computers already do)

Looking at the probability of only *one* of these assumptions means that it is already not something you have to fear. The only way for this to be at all feasible (assuming its possible with current technology) is if you were targeted personally by a team of skilled hackers, with *lots* of resources. And if you *are* targeted personally, well, you've got much bigger problems.

TL;DR: Its *not* easy. At all. Dont worry, you can Trust your mouse (pun intended).

Comment: I too think that OP's mouse is most definitively safe. However, I heavily disagree with your assumptions of the form »***one-size-fits-all** USB firmware virus*« and »*malicious firmware [...] **work on any platform***«. I never heard of one-size-fits-all malware and cannot imagine one as I cannot imagine a technical security hole that would affect every technical system (= hardware + OS + applications). Maybe on the human side, but I think this is off-topic here.

Comment: Just like most malware only targets (popular software on) Windows, I could imagine malware targeting only Trust mice. Manufacturers can re-use the same chip and firmware for different devices, so the malware doesn't even have to be device-specific. **TL;DR:** Is it *possible*? Yes! Is it *likely*? No, not at all, because the attacker has to invest much work but won't get much back in return. However, there has been malware written out of curiosity rather than malicious or financial interests (e.g. Morris worm).

Comment: I agree that it would be almost impossible to make something that targets all platforms, unless you had malicious microcode running on the CPU (which, theoretically, _could_ interface with the USB device without the OS knowing about it) but that's even harder to achieve, and realistically impossible. I hesitate to say it _is_ impossible for sure, because new things are being made all the time (think of all the new side channel attacks we hear of, for example) but my main point stands; anyone who has the resources to hack a mouse like that, can get what they want easier any other number of ways

Comment: I also agree that, yes, it's likely and even probable that Trust re-uses hardware and firmware for their mice, even years apart. If it ain't broke, why fix it? So while it's more likely to have a Windows virus floating around that targets Trust mice, you're right in that there's no incentive for a hacker to make one. If OP was specifically targeted, it would be cheaper and quicker for the assailant to just nab them off the street and use physical coercion than to make a virus just for him. This [xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png) comes to mind :)